# How to add a gridview to a C# winforms project with a list of objects as the datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview

I'm building a winforms application with C# in Visual Studio 2015 community. In this project I have a class built as so:

```
public class EDIFile
    {
        public string fullInFilePath { get; set; }
        public string fullOutFilePath { get; set; }
        public string InfileName { get; set; }
        public string OutfileName { get; set; }
        public string UniqueID { get; set; }
        public DateTime infileDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime outfileDateTime { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan timeDiff { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a list built of this class. After it is loaded I would like to have a gridview that is populated with the contents of this list. I've looked online and I've found a couple of solutions but none of them have worked for me. Please help me out with some specific instructions if you can. Thanks in advance.

I still haven't gotten it to work for me yet. Based off of the two answers here is the code that I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProviderPayProject1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load_1(object sender, List<EDIFile> EDIFiles)
        {
            DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = EDIFiles;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code from "form2" that is called from "form1". all "form2" should do is load and populate a datagridview based off of a list that is passed to the form. Please help me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure I understand your question, if you are looking to create `DataGridView` through code you could do this.

```
List<EDIFile> data; // construct your data.
DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
grid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
this.Controls.Add(grid);

grid.DataSource = data;
```

Other option, add `DataGidView` control through designer and set the `DataSource`.

```
ex..
List<EDIFile> data; // construct your data.
dataGridView1.DataSource =data;
```

Comment: See my edited original question above, I've come up with some new code but it doesn't work as I'd hoped it would.

Comment: So what is the issue now? is it throwing any error or not displaying? It would helpful if you provide some details around.

Comment: when the form2 is displayed the formgridview is blank, it doesn't display any data, the whole control is just blank.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code, its pretty simple. When the form is loaded it sets the DataGridViews datasource.

Steps are pretty simple:

- Create winform app and just add one control, a `DataGridView` and name it. In this example its simply named `dataGridView1`. *You'll need to figure this step out yourself though*.
- Determine how the `DataSource` for how the DataGridView will be set, in this example, it is set when the form is loaded, the `Form1_Load()` function. You could do this based on a click of a button.
- Create code to create a `List<EDIFile>` list. In this example `GetDataGridViewData()` returns `List<EDIFile>`. It basically creates 10 dummy `EDIFile` objects
- Set `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`

Assuming you have the winform from the first step, you should be able to change the namespace `WindowsFormsApplication1` and the Form class `Form1` to what you need:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // the list of EDFiles 
        public List<EDIFile> EDFiles { get; set; }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Load += Form1_Load; // add Form Load eventhandler
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the form is loaded
        /// </summary>
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // get dummy data
            EDFiles = GetDataGridViewData();
            // set datasource to the dummy data
            dataGridView1.DataSource = EDFiles;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns dummy data for the datagridview
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private List<EDIFile> GetDataGridViewData()
        {
            // bascially just creates dummy data for the example,
            // you'll need to implement based on how you need it to be
            var newEDFiles = new List<EDIFile>();
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
                var infileDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                var outfileDateTime = infileDateTime.AddDays(randomNumber);
                var edfile = new EDIFile()
                {
                    fullInFilePath = "fullInFilePath" + i,
                    fullOutFilePath = "fullOutFilePath" + i,
                    InfileName = "InfileName" + i,
                    OutfileName = "InfileName" + i,
                    UniqueID = "UniqueID" + i,
                    infileDateTime = infileDateTime,
                    outfileDateTime = outfileDateTime,
                    timeDiff = outfileDateTime- infileDateTime
                };
                newEDFiles.Add(edfile);
            }
            return newEDFiles;
        }
    }
    public class EDIFile
    {
        public string fullInFilePath { get; set; }
        public string fullOutFilePath { get; set; }
        public string InfileName { get; set; }
        public string OutfileName { get; set; }
        public string UniqueID { get; set; }
        public DateTime infileDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime outfileDateTime { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan timeDiff { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My example looks like this:
[image]

Comment: See my edited original question above, I've come up with some new code but it doesn't work as I'd hoped it would.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Form1` class for the button click event you'll need the following:

```
var f2 = new Form2();
f2.ShowForm(GetDataGridViewData());
```

And `Form2` class should look like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ShowForm(List<EDIFile> EDIFiles)
    {
        DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        Controls.Add(dataGridView1);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = EDIFiles;
        this.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```